# how to understand enumerate type enum which is defined inside of a namespace in c++?

Tags: c++

```
enum StudentNames
{
    KENNY, // 0
    KYLE, // 1
    STAN, // 2
    BUTTERS, // 3
    CARTMAN, // 4
    WENDY, // 5
    MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};

int main()
{
    int testScores[MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
    testScores[STAN] = 76; // still works

    return 0;
}
```

This works. While on the other hand, the following code does not work.

```
enum class StudentNames
{
    KENNY, // 0
    KYLE, // 1
    STAN, // 2
    BUTTERS, // 3
    CARTMAN, // 4
    WENDY, // 5
    MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};

int main()
{
    int testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
    testScores[StudentNames::STAN] = 76;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I got the following error:

```
$ g++ array2.cpp
array2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
array2.cpp:14:46: error: size of array ‘testScores’ has non-integral type ‘StudentNames’
     int testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
                                              ^
array2.cpp:15:34: error: array subscript is not an integer
     testScores[StudentNames::STAN] = 76;
```

I think it's because `StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS` in `testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]` is not of integral type, indeed it is of type enum in c++, right?

Once again, the following works.

```
namespace StudentNames
{
    enum StudentNames
    {
        KENNY, // 0
        KYLE, // 1
        STAN, // 2
        BUTTERS, // 3
        CARTMAN, // 4
        WENDY, // 5
        MAX_STUDENTS // 6
    };
}

int main()
{
    int testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
    testScores[StudentNames::STAN] = 76;

    return 0;
}
```

I was confused about the very last piece of code. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** My main concern is, why it works again in the third piece of code.

Comment: Regular `enum`s can be implicitly converted to integers, but `enum class`es can not. You need a cast: `int(StudentNames::STAN)`.

Comment: doing some reasearch before asking would have helped. What you observe was one of the main reasons to introduce `enum class`

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly confused you. Did you think that something placed in a namespace becomes something radically different?

Answer (score 0):

> why it works again in the third piece of code.

For the same reason as it works in the first piece of code: Because `enum`s are implicitly convertible to their underlying type, which is an integer.

> I think [second example fails] because `StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS` ... is not of integral type, indeed it is of type enum in c++, right?

It is of type `StudentNames`, which is an enum class. Enum classes are not implicitly convertible to their underlying type. They must be converted explicitly.

Comment: I guess you mean, in the third piece of code, StudentNames in testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS] refers to the namespace StudentNames, right? But why it is not referring to the StudentNames type ?

Comment: @kkxx Because there is no type `StudentNames` in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This enumeration

```
enum StudentNames
{
    KENNY, // 0
    KYLE, // 1
    STAN, // 2
    BUTTERS, // 3
    CARTMAN, // 4
    WENDY, // 5
    MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};
```

is an unscoped enumeration. According to the C++ 17 Standard (10.2 Enumeration declarations)

> 10 The value of an enumerator or an object of an unscoped enumeration
>   type is converted to an integer by integral promotion (7.6).

And this

```
enum class StudentNames
{
    KENNY, // 0
    KYLE, // 1
    STAN, // 2
    BUTTERS, // 3
    CARTMAN, // 4
    WENDY, // 5
    MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};
```

is a scoped enumeration. The previous quote from the Standard is appended with

> Note that this implicit enum to int conversion is not provided for a
>   scoped enumeration:

So to convert an enumeratod of a scoped enumeration to an integer type you have to cast it explicitly to the integer type.

Enumeratods of unscoped enumeration may have a qualified type. This allows to specify what enumerator of wht enumeration is used. Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color { Red = 0 };

int main() 
{
    enum Color { Red = 10 };

    std::cout << Color::Red << '\n';
    std::cout << ::Color::Red << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
0
```

Now let's one of the enumerations will be a scoped enumeration. In this case the program will look like

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color { Red = 0 };

int main() 
{
    enum class Color { Red = 10 };

    std::cout << static_cast<int>( Color::Red ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ::Color::Red << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```